# How come my recent questions are not viewed by anyone on SO?

Tags: discussion, bug

I asked 2 questions on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035414/how-to-implement-push-servers-load-balanced-with-nginx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072304/how-to-stop-browser-from-caching-websocket-messages-in-case-of-broken-connection

But it seems they are not viewed by anyone except myself, why is this happening? Am I in some kind of 'inactive user list'? or blocked?

Comment: That second one is only an hour old.

Comment: I know, but the first one has been posted for 2 days. And the views are mostly me opening the page, this doesn't happen *normally*.

Comment: @NeoWang Views are per user, not per refresh, as far as I remember.

Comment: I think, that your questions are too special to get a lot of attention.

Comment: "Special" isn't always a good thing.

Comment: The [Tumbleweed badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) (Asked a question with zero score, no answers, no comments, and low views for a week) wouldn't exist if it wasn't possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the questions cited has nothing to do with programming and would be better off on another site.

Network architecture, better off on Server Fault:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035414/how-to-implement-push-servers-load-balanced-with-nginx

The other question is too broad and gives no evidence of what you tried or any kind of code:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33072304/how-to-stop-browser-from-caching-websocket-messages-in-case-of-broken-connection

Both will be closed.

In general, though, how about a little patience? You posted this within an hour of posting the question(s). You are about to experience the Meta Effect.